# Removing timestamp from date using INNERJOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, timestamp, inner-join

I found a lot of things here, but nothing helped me. I can remove timestamp, but I can't remove it when I use `INNER JOIN`. I tried many things, but it does not work.

Here it is what am I trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DATE) "END_DATE", LO_ID 
FROM 
    dbo.LO as L 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.IL as I ON L.LO_ID = I.LO_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PO as P ON P.LO_ID = I.LO_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CO as C ON P.CO_ID = C.ID 
WHERE 
    P.LO = 7
```

I get error at LO_ID. How can I remove timestamp when I use `INNER JOIN` ?

I've also tried `CONVERT` method instead of `CAST`.

PS: This is the result I want to get:

```
SELECT * FROM loan.LOANS as L 
INNER JOIN insurance.INSURANCES as I ON L.LOAN_ID = I.LOAN_ID 
INNER JOIN insurance.POLICIES as P ON P.LOAN_ID = I.LOAN_ID 
INNER JOIN insurance.COMPANIES as C ON P.COMPANY_ID = C.ID WHERE P.LOAN_ID = 7
```

This works fine and this is what I expect for, but in all Date has a timestamp and I just want to remove that timestamp

[image]

Comment: You didn't specify which table's LO_ID you want in the select field.

Comment: @brithwulf It's not clear what you pretend to achieve, you should provide a sample of data in LOANS and INSURANCE, and show what result you would want to get from that data.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with this query ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, [L.END_DATE]) as LOAN_END_DATE, 
       CONVERT(date, [I.END_DATE]) as INSURANCE_END_DATE, 
       L.LOAN_ID 
FROM loan.LOANS as L 
     INNER JOIN insurance.INSURANCES as I ON L.LOAN_ID = I.LOAN_ID 
     INNER JOIN insurance.POLICIES as P ON P.LOAN_ID = I.LOAN_ID 
     INNER JOIN insurance.COMPANIES as C ON P.COMPANY_ID = C.ID WHERE P.LOAN_ID = 7
```

You should be able to remove the time part of every returned field using the convert function. It doesn't matter if the returned fields come from the main table or the joined tables.

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'END_DATE', this is the error what I get.

Comment: Then you have END_DATE columns at more than one table, you need to use their aliases to differentiate them. I have updated the answer to show those END_DATE with aliases.